# Code counts the number of identical elements between the arrays 's' and 'd' at the same index

Tags: java, performance

I wrote a code and the code counts the number of identical elements between the arrays `s` and `d` at the same index. I need to optimize the code for speed and readability. I tried HashSet but it didn't work at all. Do you have any Suggestions?

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    { Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();

        while (t-- > 0) {

            int a = sc.nextInt(); //

            int count = 0;
            int s[] = new int[a];
            int d[] = new int[a];

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                s[i] = sc.nextInt();

            }
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {


                d[j] = sc.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

                    if (s[i] == d[i]) {

                        count++;
                       
                    }


                }


            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get better answers if you ask better questions. My answer and Justin's answer improve on the code as provided, greybeard's discusses a more general approach. The question is whether the code you provided, which reads input as 
1) number of sets
2) size of this set
3) first list of numbers
4) second list of numbers
5) continue from 2
is the model you want/have to work with or just a way of producing the lists, but you want a general answer - the best answer is very much dependent on this.

Comment: (@MarkBluemel 1) number of *lengths & pairs of sequences*, actually, or *#test cases*.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the third "for" loop do you? Nor do you really need the second array. Think about it...

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the input is not readily apparent from the example, so I wasn't able to rigorously test my changes.
Several ideas:

- make the indentation / spacing consistent
- use `for` instead of `while` when the number of iterations is known
- use (++i) instead of (i++) if you only need the incremented value
- use the same iterator name for the same depth of loop nesting (i, j)
- reduce the number of loops by storing only the first half of each subarray
- braces are optional for single statements

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{ 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int m = sc.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) 
    {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        int first_half[] = new int[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
            first_half[j] = sc.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (first_half[j] == sc.nextInt()) 
                ++count;

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps. It would be tough to optimize further; look at [java.util.Arrays](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Arrays-source.html) line 787 and you'll see that they aren't much fancier.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation, Justin.

Comment: I get *storing only half as much*. I still don't understand *storing only the first half **of each subarray*** - the first array from each test-case?

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting suggestions to not compare two arrays due to the way you coded *count the number of identical elements between the arrays 's' and 'd' at the same index*.

Generally, put *business logic* in its own procedure:
You get to name *and document* procedure and parameters.

```
    /** @return the count of identical elements at the same index 
     * in <code>int</code> arrays <code>a</code> and <code>b</code>. */
    int countOfIdenticalElementsAtSameIndex(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return countOfIdenticalElementsAtSameIndex(a, b, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    /** @return the count of identical elements at the same index 
     * in <code>int</code> arrays <code>a</code> and <code>b</code>, 
     * for 0 <= index < <code>limit</code>.
     */
    int countOfIdenticalElementsAtSameIndex(int[] a, int[] b, int limit) {
        if (null == a || null == b)
            return 0;
        int count = 0;
        limit = Math.min(Math.min(a.length, b.length), limit)
        for (int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++)
            if (a[i] == b[i])
                count += 1;
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: I read both `++i` and `i++` on their own as *next `i`*, and `i++` was there in K&R. I use `+= 1` where I think *increase by 1* - code the way *you* think.

Comment: I (and probably most people) would find `if (a == null || b == null)` more readable. The _only_ time Yoda expressions might have a purpose in Java is when testing Boolean variables. That's the _only_ time you might inadvertently use `=` instead of `==` and still be able to compile the line.

Comment: (@k314159 I did mention habits from C days.)

Answer (score 1):

- (Said already) here you need only the first array.
- You do not separate the tasks of first reading and then comparing. It would be nice if you could already create functions, "methods."
- Testing the speed of the application can only sensibly be done redirecting a file to `System.in` as in `java MyClass <data.txt`. As keyboard input cannot be measured. Then one would see that `Scanner` has a bit overhead.
- The main thing here is the style, readability. `count` can be introduced *after* reading the data here.

Then a tip: you are using an array style introduced to let Java look more like C and C++:

```
int a[] = ...
```

But more logical is keeping the type parts together:

```
int[] a = ...
```

The C compatibility syntax is a dead giveaway of a new inexperienced developer.

I would have liked to see:

```
int length = scanner.nextInt();
int[] first = readArray(scanner, length);
int[] second = readArray(scanner, length);
int same = identical(first, second);
System.out.println(...);
```

There is not much to optimize here.

You could have chosen to read two lines of text, each containing one array.